# Antlr4 Lexer with two continuous parentheses

Tags: antlr4

My text is : Function(argument, function(argument)). When I use g4 DEBUGGER to generate the tree. It will works when there is blank between the last two parentheses: Function(argument, function(argument) ). But the debugger will say unexpected '))' when there is not a blank. So, how should I revise my grammar to make it?

It confuses me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(It will be much easier to confirm the answer to your question if you post the grammar, or at least a stripped down version that demonstrates the issue.  Note: Often, stripping down to a minimal example to demonstrate the issue will result in you finding your own answer.)

That said, based upon your error message, I would guess that you have a Lexer rule that matches `))`.  If you do, then ANTLR will match that rule and create that token rather than creating two `)` tokens.

Most of the time this mistake originates from not understanding that the Lexer is completely independent of the parser.  The Lexer recognizes streams of characters and produces a stream of tokens, and then the parser matched rules against that stream of tokens.  In this case, I would guess that the parser rule is looking to match a `)` token, but finds the `))` token instead.  Those are two different tokens, so the parser rule will fail.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions about posting more details! And thanks again for your help again. Because I fixed my problem with your guide! I found there is a '))' in another parser rule, although it is not the parser rule one is needed by my text posted here. It is wired. Why does a '))' in other parser rules will effect the tokenization of unrelated rules?

Comment: parser rules have NO impact on tokenization.  Your stream of tokens is determined by the Lexer, and the parser acts on that stream of tokens.  If you have a `')'` directly in your parser rule (and probably a `'))'` in another rule), these are just convenient ways to implicitly declare Lexer rules.   The fact that you declare them in a parser rule has no bearing on this.  (I can see where this could lead to some confusion, but it is a nice convenience that can improve the readability of parser rules.